# How can I estimate missing bounding box outputs using known bounding box data of a sequence?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box

I am getting vehicle detections from YOLO with a video input. And I got some missing bounding box outputs for some frames. How can I get bounding box estimations for those missing frames using other known bounding boxes and centers of that sequence just by using coordinate geometry without using any advance tracking method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to just interpolate between adjacent frames. When a bounding box is missing in a frame but is present in adjacent frames, you can take the coordinates of the bounding boxes and calculate the average. If you want to make it more eleborate you can even include more frames and add a weight to weigh closer frames heavier.